# Obtain Spotify API OAuth 2.0 token with PHP

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, spotify

I am trying to obtain a `OAuth 2.0` token for the Spotify API using the following guide:
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/

I have the following PHP code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
  'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode('MY_CLIENT_CODE:MY_CLIENT_SECRET')
]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode([
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
]));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
print_r($result);
```

But the result is:

```
Array ( [error] => unsupported_grant_type [error_description] => grant_type parameter is missing )
```

Their [example code is JavaScript](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/) and apparently I don't understand it well enough to translate it to PHP. Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are json encoding the form fields, you should build a query parameter.

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query([
  'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
]));
```